# changing dynamic url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following url structure:

```
www.mysite.com/temporary/articles.php?artid=1
```

I would like to change it with

```
www.mysite.com/temporary/articles/article-title-here.
```

Anyone can tell me how can I do that?

Also I have links with two varialbes in it:

```
www.mysite.com/temporary/products.php?catid=1&productid=1
```

Which I am trying to make it:

```
www.mysite.com/temporary/products.php/category-name/product-name
```

Thanks in advance.

Zoran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you're going to need some type of script that can map article/category/product names to IDs. You're on your own as far as writing this script, but it can go something along the lines of this:

1. If there's a query-string variable `article-name`, then take its value, lookup the database (or whatever storage you are using) and see what the article ID is, then load `/temporary/articles.php?artid=ID`, where ID is the ID of the given title.
2. If there's a query-string variable `product-name` and/or `category-name`, lookup the database to see what the category and product IDs are for those names, then load `/temporary/products.php?catid=1&productid=1` using the appropriate IDs.
3. otherwise, do something like return a 404

The associated rewrite rules to make this happen assuming that this php script you've written is at `/my-controller.php`

```
RewriteRule ^temporary/articles/(.+)$ /my-controller.php?article-name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^temporary/products.php/([^/]+)/(.+) /my-controller.php?category-name=$1&product-name=$2
```

So if someone requests http://www.mysite.com/temporary/articles/foo-article, it will be rewritten to `/my-controller.php?article-name=foo-article` and when someone requests http://www.mysite.com/temporary/products.php/bars/foo-product, it will be rewritten to `/my-controller.php?category-name=bars&product-name=foo-product` and it's up to the script you write to do the necessary ID lookup, then pass it to either the articles.php or products.php scripts.