# Wordpress : How to get a RestFUL URL for a function?

Tags: wordpress, function, rest, url, variables

I have a basic custom function which accept GET/POST requests, and process them upon request. Just simply (Lets say GET now):

```
function miccheck() {
    echo "Hello, Mic Check 123! ". $_GET["specialguest"];
}
add_action( 'wp', 'miccheck' );
```

Then, simply i can call that function from URL as like:

```
http://www.example.com/?specialguest=JACKIE
```

Then the home page appeared with `Hello, Mic Check 123! JACKIE`.
All simiply.

Then, now i want a specific entry point with RestFUL URL. Like:

```
http://www.example.com/miccheck/?specialguest=JACKIE
or either
http://www.example.com/miccheck/specialguest/JACKIE
```

Even the first one is ok, as long as i have a specific entry point. How to do it in Wordpress, please?

Answer (score 1):

### I experienced in my case

`http://example.com?error=NoData&p=-999` redirect wordpress to 404 page and `$_GET['error']` gives `NoData`. However, if the position of `error` and `p` are swapped, then $_GET['error'] gives nothing. I guess wordpress queries stop processing after it gets a `p` (just guess, not sure).

**The trick I apply here is:** 
 I use $_REQUEST array which gives both of `error` and `p` (regardless of their position). Remember this thing, I will use this info to provide solution.

For `example.com/param1/param2/.../paramN` format, you need to edit **.htcaccess file** also. I have no experience with editing .htcaccess file and do not advise to use it unless you are familiar with it.

---

### Idea of solution

If you create a menu page/submenu page then the wordpress url becomes as: `http://example.com/wordpressLocation/wp-admin/admin.php?action=PageHandleName&otherParam=bla-bla-bla`.
 
So, here there is an entry point (PageHandler) and it must be activated/stored beforehand so there is no risk in providing entrypoint function name.

---

### Suggested solution

I would take **miccheck** as another parameter and call example.com only. So, generate your url as: `example.com/?entryPoint=miccheck&specialGuest=Jack`. Then inside `$_REQUEST['miccheck']` you will find the function name to call and `$_REQUEST['specialGuest']` will contain data.

**Security risk:**
Taking the entrypoint name as variable and calling a function by user provided variable might have huge security risk. You should maintain a separate array inside your code just to make sure only allowed functions are called. Say, your code might become:

```
$listOfFunction = array('miccheck','restCheck');
if( $_REQUEST['entryPoint']) not in $listOfFunction)
  throw new Exception('invalid entry point');
```

Comment: `Suggested Solution` still can't give `/miccheck/?......` solution? :S Should i just create a new Folder there? ><

Comment: You need to use .htcaccess then. Some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379561/htaccess-rule-apply-query-string-rule-and-change-the-url . From (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667549/changing-dynamic-url-with-htaccess?rq=1) url, I think you need to write conditions as:

`RewriteRule ^/miccheck/(.+)$ /LocationToWordpressIndex.php?entryPoint=miccheck&specialGuest=$1 [L]`

which takes /miccheck/jack as entry and redirect accordingly so that you can use $_REDIRECT thing.